# Swift Tableview checkmark disappeared after relaunch viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my case, I am loading `JSON` data into `tableview`. Here, the tableview cell multiple cell selection `checkmark` and `uncheckmark` options implemented. If go previous `viewcontroller` and comeback again tableview controller then last selected checkmark disappeared. How to `store` it?

**JSON Codable**

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: Bool
    let data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable, Hashable {
    let userid, firstname, designation: String?
    let profileimage: String?
}
```

**Custom Cell Class**

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameCellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleCellLabel: UILabel!
}
```

**Code for Tableview Checkmark**

```
 var studentsData = [Datum]()
 var sessionData = Set<Datum>()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
        let item = self.studentsData[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameCellLabel.text = item.firstname
        cell.subtitleCellLabel.text = item.designation
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let item = self.studentsData[indexPath.row]
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                cell.accessoryType = .none

                // UnCheckmark cell JSON data Remove from array
                self.sessionData.remove(item)
                print(sessionData)

            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

                // Checkmark selected data Insert into array
                self.sessionData.insert(item)
                print(sessionData)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Write it into your model (`studentsData`).

Comment: @matt sorry. I am new for this please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You should always save the checkMark status in another array or variable.
In case only one item can be selected:

```
var SELECTED_ITEMS= [YOUR_DATA_TYPE]()//It must be global within tableViewController
```

in case multiple selection allowed

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            let item = self.studentsData[indexPath.row]
            if SELECTED_ITEMS.contain(item){
                SELECTED_ITEMS.remove(item)
            }else{
                SELECTED_ITEMS.append(item)
            }
}
```

Remember SELECTED_ITEM should be Array of your tableviewdata and SELECTED_ITEM is just the same type of your tableview data.
Also if you are initializing your model in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear in tableview controller, make should `SELECTED_ITEMS` and `SELECTED_ITEM` are not reset when tableview appears.

then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          ........
           cell.accessoryView = SELECTED_ITEMS.contain(item) ? .checkmark:.none// Multi Selection
          .........

    }
```

In general, you update your model, a variable or array or whatever fits in your code to keep a track of which indexpath is select/unselected. Then in cellForRowAt you can check the above variable/array... to set accessory.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){}
```

will also work

Comment: What I need to mention inside cellforRow method

Comment: Than you so much for your reply. Btw I am using Tableview within Viewcontroller also multiple cell selection check mark available. Could you please update your code?

Comment: thank you buddy. I have done this question by my own try :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a means to store the checkmark status within your data struct

```
struct Datum: Codable, Hashable {
    let userid, firstname, designation: String?
    let profileimage: String?
    var selected: Bool = false
}
```

Set the value when you create a cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
        let item = self.studentsData[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameCellLabel.text = item.firstname
        cell.subtitleCellLabel.text = item.designation
        cell.accessoryType = item.selected ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }
```

And then in the `didSelectRowAt` replace the `if` block with the below to save the change back to the student data and then reset the checkmark accordingly:

```
 self.studentsData[indexPath.row].selected.toggle()
 cell.accessoryType = studentsData[indexPath.row].selected ? .checkmark : .none
```

Comment: @mobileapps, do you mean the checkmark doesn't appear when you select the cell?  Have you tried setting `selected = true` initially and seeing if that shows up?

Comment: @flanker initially where I need to give `selected = true`?

Comment: @flanker I have added my JSON `"selected": false` for all values.

Comment: numerous possible places - wherever you instantiate the recrods, or by setting the default to true in the struct definition, or even in cellForRowAt.  It's just a test so you can see if the TV will display a checkmark.